# Why does GHC complain about the missing `Typeable` instance even if I specify is as a type restriction?

Tags: haskell

Why does the following code not compile even if I added the `Typeable` boundary to satisfy the [`cast`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.3.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast) function's requirements?

```hs
import           Data.Data

a :: Maybe Int
a = cast f
  where
    f :: Typeable a => a
    f = undefined
```

```
app/Main.hs:6:5: error:
    • No instance for (Typeable a0) arising from a use of ‘cast’
    • In the expression: cast f
      In an equation for ‘a’:
          a = cast f
            where
                f :: Typeable a => a
                f = undefined
  |
6 | a = cast f
  |     ^^^^
```

`Maybe Int` should implement the type class because the following code compiles.

```hs
import           Data.Data

b :: String
b = show $ typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy (Maybe Int))
```

(I'm not asking how to cast a value, e.g., from `Int` to `String`. I'm just curious about this  strange error.)

GHC: 9.2.2

Comment: `TypeApplications` are a good habit, by writing `cast @Int @String` you are unambiguous about what you're casting to what. Also you probably want to import `cast` from `Data.Typeable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write a polymorphic declaration like that you are basically saying i can produce any `a` that has a `Typeable` instance. Then the caller decides which `a` to instantiate the type variable. For example

```
b :: String
b = show f
  where
    f :: (Show a) => a
    f = undefined -- for example you cannot write f="x"
```

this produces a similar error. It is not specified anywhere in the program what `a` should be used.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you never specify the type that `f` should have before the cast. You could equally well do

```
a :: Maybe Int
a = cast (f :: Int)
 where f :: Typeable a => a
       f = undefined
```

(which would yield `Just ⊥`) or

```
a :: Maybe Int
a = cast (f :: [String])
 where f :: Typeable a => a
       f = undefined
```

(which would yield `Nothing`).

Some constraints would cause the compiler to *default* an unspecified type, e.g. a `Num` context would default to `Integer`. But `Typeable` does not default to anything, so the compiler baulks.